# Kafka: The message when serialized is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

Getting the following error (Kafka 2.1.0):

> 2018-12-03 21:22:37.873 ERROR 37645 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when
>   sending a message with key='null' and payload='{82, 73, 70, 70, 36,
>   96, 19, 0, 87, 65, 86, 69, 102, 109, 116, 32, 16, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
>   68, -84,...' to topic recieved_sound: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 1269892 bytes when serialized which is larger than the
>   maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size
>   configuration.

I tried all the suggestions in various SO posts.

My Producer.properties:

```
max.request.size=41943040
message.max.bytes=41943040
replica.fetch.max.bytes=41943040
fetch.message.max.bytes=41943040
```

Server.properties:

```
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
message.max.bytes=41943040
max.request.size=41943040
replica.fetch.max.bytes=41943040
fetch.message.max.bytes=41943040
```

ProducerConfig (Spring Boot):

```
configProps.put("message.max.bytes", "41943040");
configProps.put("max.request.size", "41943040");
configProps.put("replica.fetch.max.bytes", "41943040");
configProps.put("fetch.message.max.bytes", "41943040");
```

ConsumerConfig (SpringBoot):

```
props.put("fetch.message.max.bytes", "41943040");
props.put("message.max.bytes", "41943040");
props.put("max.request.size", "41943040");
props.put("replica.fetch.max.bytes", "41943040");
props.put("fetch.message.max.bytes", "41943040");
```

I also changed Strings to numbers in the last 2 files. Started brokers multiple times, and created new topics. I was getting `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The request included a message larger than the max message size the server will accept` error initially, which got fixed by these changes, but still no luck with this new error.

Comment: Your configurations look fine. I am guessing maybe you did not deploy the changeds to all brokers? [Can you check the broker config using bin/kafka-configs.sh](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#dynamicbrokerconfigs) to make sure your configurations are correct on all brokers?

Comment: also add `max.partition.fetch.bytes`

Comment: `max.partition.fetch.bytes` is a soft limit. from documentation: `If the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this limit, the batch will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress`.

Comment: You might need to add kaka.max.partition.fetch.bytes instead of max.partition.fetch.bytes to the client properties

Answer (score 10):

Set a breakpoint in `KafkaProducer.ensureValidRecordSize()` to see what's going on.

With this app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So53605262Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53605262Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so53605262", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> template.send("so53605262", new String(new byte[1024 * 1024 * 2]));
    }

}
```

I get

> The message is 2097240 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.

as expected; when I add

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.request.size=3000000
```

(which is the equivalent of your config but using Spring Boot properties), I get

> The request included a message larger than the max message size the server will accept.

If debugging doesn't help, perhaps you can post a complete small app that exhibits the behavior you see.

Answer (score 2):

You can change message size if Kafka property is file on a server.

for default sever.property file

```
#/usr/local/kafka/config
#message.max.bytes=26214400
```

producer.properties->

```
# the maximum size of a request in bytes
# max.request.size=26214400
```

same for conusmer

Answer (score 0):

I realise the thread is old; nonetheless, for those who, like myself, find this post when grappling with publishing large messages to kafka:

To get the `max_request_size=3145764` (3Mb)to work for the local producer I needed to set compression_type='lz4' in `KafkaProducer` settings:

```
self.producer = KafkaProducer(
compression_type='lz4', 
max_request_size=3145764,
...,
)
```

Note: `compression_type` may be: lz4, gzip or snappy.

Without setting the `compression_type` local producer was unable to deliver messages larger than 1Mb to kafka irrespectively of having `max_request_size` set to 3 Mb.

Answer (score -3):

**You should set config in producer in such way**

```
Props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, "41943040");
```

Comment: It's Props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, "41943040");